# I need to create a function to refresh a webpage with two user-selected date parameters

Tags: html, url, url-routing

It looks like I can create a date-range selection tool using the instructions here:http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/136-how-to-create-a-calendar-date-picker-with-javascript/

But I want to then take those two dates, insert them into the URL and reload the page when a user selects 'submit' after choosing two dates... which will then limit the data displayed to only that date range.  That functionality is already available but right now I have to manually type in the beginning and end date. I want to code it into the page so that there are two calendar pickers that I submit, then the url is updated with those and the data is reloaded on the page.

Can someone point me in the right direction about how to do this?

Many thanks from a coding noob!

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['method']) && $_GET['method'] == 'set-date-range' ) {
    // Do stuff with the dates
    // $_GET['date-one']
    // $_GET['date-two']
}
?>

<form action="mygraph.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="set-date-range">
    <input type="text" name="date-one" />
    <input type="text" name="date-two" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

*Edit:*

When you submit the form, it will "refresh" the page (since it is pointing back to itself) and you'll have easy access to those dates up in the URL. So anywhere in that page, you can `$_GET['whatever-date-you-want']` and `echo` it out or whatever you wish.

Note: The extension of your page needs to be .php instead of .html so that you have the option to write some PHP code.

*Edit 2:*

So, when you submit the form, the URL will look like:

`...mygraph.php?method=set-date-range&date-one=1-1-2012&date-two=10-2-2012`

You can then access those dates like this:

`$_GET['date-one']` or `$_GET['date-two']`

Comment: Sorry - not very familiar with PHP.... What would I need to do to insert it into a URL call like http:// www.mywebsite. com/mygraph.html?getdate1=date-one&getdate2=date-two